Did the Western Powers decline overtures from the Soviet Union to fight Hitler?
In this lecture by Michael Parenti, he claims (starting from 07:31) that England, the United States, and France declined an alliance overtures from the Soviet Union against the German Reich so "Hitler can go east":

Parenti: No, I'm not—can't say it that way—Li[tvinov] went to the Western Powers and called for an alliance with England, the United States, and France against Nazi Germany; and that if the Germans attacked Czechoslovakia, they would all join in—or attacked Poland or attacked anybody—that all the powers would join in at—to fight Hitler and contain him. The Western Allies refused those overtures from the Soviet Union—not because they were appeasers—not because they were simple and naïve—quite the contrary—because they had a plan of their own, and that plan was Munich! And the plan was "we give Hitler Czechoslovakia, and he goes East!" And they were waiting for war, and that war was supposed to come, and it was going to be Nazi Germany finishing off Bolshevik Russia! Just as they had sent armies in against Russia just a few years—less than a decade before—so they now planned to do the same, and so they've done again and again!

Is that true that England, the United States, and France refused the alliance so Bolshevik Russia can be 'finished'?

Litvinov did make such a proposal. The allies were in the process of negotiating when Poland was invaded, whether in good or bad faith I'm not sure. What is left out is that shortly after Litvinov made his proposal he was fired by Stalin and replaced by Molotov because the Soviets wanted to be closer to Germany and Litvinov wanted the opposite.

Isn't this asking about motivation, and hence unanswerable in its current form?

@JeromeViveiros No as there can be a factual answer - did Litvinov make such a request and was it rejected. However this is after historical facts and so should be on History SE not Skeptics

@mmmmmm I agree, this is a better fit for History.SE.

I agree with Schwern, [history.se] is a better place for it. (If true, it would seem to be at odds with everything I've learned - so I'll be watching keenly)

Factchecking a claim about history can be skepticism, I think

It can yes, but the folks there are more familiar with the ins and outs and where to find such things than we are likely to be. @Riemann Standards for historic research are a bit different from scientific ones - which we're more accustomed to.

Can we migrate this to History? Everybody seems to think it would be a better fit.

Parenti is a very pro-Soviet commentator—actually kind of rare among modern left-wing commentators, who are more likely to consider Stalinism a kind of quasi-fascist corruption of "true" Marxist ideals. I suspect that accounts for the focus on Litvinov over the Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact, or later Soviet collaboration against Germany for that matter. I guess that he is also pro-Putin now—though Putin is very far from left-wing? Even if this gets moved, then, it might be worth fact-checking his other claims about "ten years before," "again and again," and "they've now planned to do the same."

Did you do basic research, such as reading Litvinov's Wikipedia page?

"Ten years before" is easy to refute. Litvinov's treaty negotiations were in 1938. The Russian Civil War was effectively over by 1919, so it's nearer 20 years. "Sent armies against Russia" is a bit of exaggeration - British and French support for the anti-Bolshevik White Russian army amounted to less than 1% of the forces and was pretty much restricted to defending ports. Not that they wouldn't have squashed Lenin's regime if they had had the chance.
